# Having Wildcard problems

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having difficulty using a wildcard in my VBA code.

```
Set OpenWB = Workbooks.Open("C:filename.csv", ReadOnly:=True)

With OpenWB.Worksheets(1)
    iTotSRows = .Range("F" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    oSourceR = .Range("A2:G" & iTotSRows)
End With
OpenWB.Close False

Set CompWB = Workbooks.Open("C:filename2.csv", ReadOnly:=True)

With CompWB.Worksheets(1)
    iTotCRows = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    oCurR = .Range("A2:f" & iTotCRows)
End With
CompWB.Close False

For iSC = 1 To UBound(oSourceR) 
    For iCC = 1 To UBound(oCurR)
        If (LCase(oCurR(iCC, 2)) = LCase(oSourceR(iSC, 2))) And (LCase(oCurR(iCC, 3)) = LCase(oSourceR(iSC, 3))) And (LCase(oCurR(iCC, 4)) = LCase(oSourceR(iSC, 4))) And (LCase(oCurR(iCC, 5)) = "*" & LCase(oSourceR(iSC, 5))) Then
            oSourceR(iSC, 7) = oCurR(iCC, 6)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next

ThsSht.Range("A2:G" & iTotSRows) = oSourceR
```

As you can see, when I am comparing values I am wanting to use a wildcard to compare (oSourceR(iSC, 5)) and (oCurR(iCC, 5)) as one is a reference number that is contained at the end of a string in the other.

Why is this not working? The rest of the code works fine if not for the wildcard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `Like` operator.

```
If (LCase(oCurR(iCC, 2)) = LCase(oSourceR(iSC, 2))) And _
   (LCase(oCurR(iCC, 3)) = LCase(oSourceR(iSC, 3))) And _
   (LCase(oCurR(iCC, 4)) = LCase(oSourceR(iSC, 4))) And _
   (LCase(oCurR(iCC, 5)) Like "*" & LCase(oSourceR(iSC, 5))) Then
        oSourceR(iSC, 7) = oCurR(iCC, 6)
        Exit For
End If
```